# Android does not have permission to read content://media/external/audio/media

Tags: xml, audio, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

In my app api level targetSdkVersion 23. I have added permission as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="my.mymetaextractor" >

            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <activity android:name=".MetaExtractActivity" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
            </application>

        </manifest>
```

When I tried to execute following:

```
    String[] STAR = {"*"};
    Uri allsongsuri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    //  Uri allsongsuri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
    Cursor cursor = null;


    try {

      this.grantUriPermission("my.mymetaextractor",        
      allsongsuri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION |     
     Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        cursor = managedQuery(allsongsuri, STAR, selection, null,  
    null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String msg = e.getMessage();
        Log.i("tag", "wait");
    }
```

I get **exception**:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Uid 10209 does not have permission to uri
>   0 @ content://media/external/audio/media

But Uri `allsongsuri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;` works. Exception for Uri `allsongsuri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;`

Note that same code works nice in older device android 4. But it happens for the android 6. I assume something is new for android 6 to add permission. Please how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask this permission at runtime not only in the manifest : [permissions](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this,  "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  )   != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
requestPermissions(new String[]{"android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"}, 0);